# How can i terminate process created with winexec()?

Tags: windows, delphi, pascal

For example i want launch cmd with WinExec() and after about 10 seconds terminate it, i wrote small code for that, but it doesn't work. Why it doesn't work and how can i fix it?

Here is my code:

```
program Project2;

uses
  Windows;

var
  hProcess: THandle;

begin
hProcess := WinExec('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe', SW_SHOW);
Sleep(10000);
TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
end.
```

Comment: Nothing in the docs suggests that the value returned is a process handle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec. I suggest (as per the docs) using CreateProcess (as well as reading that link)

Comment: At the very top of the `WinExec` docs... "`Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows. Applications should use the CreateProcess function.`" I highly doubt you intend to support 16bit applications.

Comment: Why on Earth would you expect it to work? [The MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winexec) doesn't say anything about the returned value being a process handle. Jerry Dodge is right: do as the documentation advices, and use `CreateProcess` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WinExec` does not return a process handle. In fact, its documentation makes it clear that you should not use this function at all. It only exists for backwards compatibility.

Use `CreateProcess` instead which returns a process handle via the process information argument.